# the usual topology on the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is strictly weaker than the topology induced on it by the lexicographic ordering.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the usual topology on the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is strictly weaker than the topology induced on it by the lexicographic ordering.

---

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to prove two things:

1. Every usual open set is open in the lexicographic order topology, and
2. There is at least one set that is open in the lexicographic order topology but not in the usual topology.

If $\tau$ is the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$, and $\tau'$ is the lexicographic order topology, you’re being asked to show that $\tau\subsetneqq\tau'$; (1) says that $\tau\subseteq\tau'$, and (2) says that $\tau'\nsubseteq\tau$, so the two together say that $\tau\subsetneqq\tau'$.

HINTS:

1. Let $U$ be an open set in the usual topology of the plane. For each $x\in\Bbb R$ let $$U_x=U\cap\Big(\{x\}\times\Bbb R\Big)\;,$$ and show that $U_x$ is open in the lexicographic order topology on $\Bbb R^2$. It may help to look at the projection of $U_x$ on the $y$-axis, i.e., at $\{y\in\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\in U_x\}$.
2. Consider the set $\{\langle 0,y\rangle:0<y<1\}$.